# Use ams math style in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am learning how to do equation numbering using ams math in local Jupyter notebook. As per the [documentation](https://jupyterbook.org/content/math.html), it says to make changes in `_config.yml` file. But I am not sure where to find it on my Mac. If it helps, I have the file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in `~/.jupyter` directory. But they don't look the same.

Can I kindly get some help here (example'll be appreciated), how to work with `_config.yml` file. thanks in advance.

Comment: Searching that website for `_config.yml` yields [this page](https://jupyterbook.org/start/overview.html?highlight=_config%20yml), which tells you how to set up your project...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to is for a project called `jupyter-book`. If you're using that, then, as @MattDMo said, follow the example from the tutorial and add the `_config.yml` in the folder that contains your book.

If you're using a regular Jupyter Notebook, you can disregard that and just write the LaTeX in a Markdown cell, where it will be rendered (by MathJax rather than MyST), without any extra config.